# .setHours(0,0,0,0) with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the easiest equivalent of `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` when using moment.js?

Basically, if I need a `new Date()` moment with hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds zeroed out.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

[Start of Time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

```
moment().startOf('day')
```

Comment: if you want to transform it toDate, you can do it like this moment(date).startOf("day").toDate()

Answer (score 4):

Suppose **date** is the moment object which contains the date having some hours and minutes.

You can use the following code to reset hours, minutes and seconds to 0.

```
date.utcOffset(0);
date.set({
 hour: 0,
 minute: 0,
 second: 0,
 millisecond: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to set second for example to " 0 "
`time = moment().second(0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want in string format, you can use like this:
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00")

Answer (score 0):

let todayDate = moment(0, "HH")