# Setting time part to 0 in ISO date format in moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am getting date in ISO format using moment.js using:

```
let matchDate= moment().add(1, 'day').toISOString();
```

It gives me matchDate in the form:

> 2017-08-01T18:30:00.000Z

I want to set each numeric value after T as 0 and get the result as

> 2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z

How can I do this?

Comment: At that point it's just a string, so you could just slice the string to 10 characters and add "T00:00:00.000Z". i.e. `matchDate.slice(0,10) + "T00:00:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several possibilities.

Here are some:

```
let matchDate = moment();
matchDate.set('hour', 0);
matchDate.set('minute', 0);
matchDate.set('second', 0);
matchDate.set('millisecond', 0);

matchDate.set({'hour': 0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0, 'millisecond': 0});

matchDate.hour(0);
matchDate.minute(0);
matchDate.second(0);
matchDate.millisecond(0);
```

Here is the documentation about getting and setting: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/

Or, if you don't want to set the time part and doing it in formatting, you can use this:

```
let matchDate = moment();
var dateString = matchDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `startOf(unitOfTime)` function from moment.

Here how's your code will look like:

```
let matchDate = moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').toISOString();
```

Reference answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592432/4539906